# zram swap instability

Tags: linux-mint, swap, zram

I use Mint 13 Maya with [mainline kernel 3.6.3 for Ubuntu Quantal](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.3-quantal/) on my Asus P53E Notebook.

I use zram swap that comes with the package zram-config.

I've noticed that using it the system to hangs at random moments, especially (but not always) under high memory loads. Even when 90% of memory is free (and exactly no swap in use) the notebook cannot survive in a powered state a night (8 hours).

This "hanging" behaviour is quite literal: the computer respond to exactly nothing. No mouse movement, capslock/numlock leds don't respond to the corresponding keys. Even the sysrq combinations don't work (like "BUSIER"). (I don't remember if dimming the display works). After the hard restart, there is no trace of anything odd in the system logs.

This behavior doesn't happen after I shut down the zram-config service.

Does it mean, that zram swap is not ready for production? Or is it misconfigured? How can I debug this problem?